# Devexpress ASPxGridView group order

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, aspxgridview

Hello I have a  Devexpress ASPxGridView containing groups containing some rows inside.
Lets say groups have two properties A and B. 
What I would like to achieve is to send one group having property A == "TEST" to the bottom of the grid and
other group having property A == "NOTTEST" to just above of the group we send to the bottom. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ASPxGridView behaviorally groups data first and then sorts, it is not possible to sort data in same group. In short, this is not possible.